# Js es6 class constructor function run before the constructor instantiate

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an es6 class the instantiate a variable from a function call, but the problem is it seems that the function is running before the constructor instantiated and throw an error:

```
  constructor() {
    this.userSelections = {
      types    : this.getTypes(),
      providers: this.getProvider()
    } 
  }

 getProvider() {
    // here its throw error that this.userSelections is undefined
    var activeType = this.userSelections.types.some(( type ) => {
      return type.active;
    });

  }
```

Whats is the problem and how i can handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with classes, ES6 or Babel. Here is a simplified version of your problem:

```
var foo = {
  bar: 42,
  baz: foo.bar * 2
};
```

This will throw an error because `foo` is not initialized yet at the moment `foo.bar` is accessed.

In your case, you are calling `getProvider` *during* the creation of the object you want to assign to `this.userSelections`. `this.userSelections` or its value does not exist yet, it is still being constructed.

You could initialize the value in two steps:

```
this.userSelections = {
  types: this.getTypes()
};
// now that `this.userSelections` exists, we can call `this.getProvider` without problems
this.userSelections.providers = this.getProvider();
```

or refactor your code so that `getProviders` accepts `types` as parameter, maybe something like:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    let types = this.getTypes();
    this.userSelection = {
      types,
      providers: this._getProvider(types)
    };
  }

  _getProvider(types) {
    var activeType = types.some(( type ) => {
      return type.active;
    });
    // ...
  }

  getProvider() {
    return this._getProvider(this.userSelection.types);
  }
}
```

Comment: His `this` references the `userSelections` object. He is invoking `getProviders` on the `userSelections` object.

Comment: @DanPantry: No it does not. That's not how object literals work.

Comment: My mistake. I don't know why but I forgot constructor creates an execution context.

Comment: But why this line is working this.userSelections.providers = this.getProviders();?

Comment: @user233232: Because now when `this.getProvider` is called, `this.userSelection` already exists. We created it in the previous statement: `this.userSelections = {types: this.getTypes()};`